# RPG YAJL parse array within an array

Tags: arrays, json, ibm-midrange, rpgle, yajl

New to RPG and I'm a little lost on how to do this. "data" is an array with info I need, I am able to parse this. However "cargoLoaded" is an array inside the "data" array which contains a single item "cargoSensor1". I need the value of cargoSensor1.

JSON and a portion of my code below (data areas not included).

JSON I want to parse (I need the value cargoSensor1)

```
{
   "success": true,
   "data":    [
            {
         "address": "6061 Segale Park Dr C",
         "cargoLoaded": [{"cargoSensor1": false}],
         "city": "Tukwila",
         "deviceId": 10841293,
         "eventDateTime": "2020-03-02 17:27:56",
         "eventTypeName": "Cargo Update",
         "gpsTrackedDistance": 3.029E7,
         "heading": 294,
         "id": 14364709,
         "idle": false,
         "idleStartTime": null,
         "ignitionOn": false,
         "ignitionOnStartTime": null,
         "inputs": ["ATIS Inactive"],
         "landmarkId": null,
         "landmarkName": null,
         "lat": 47.434048,
         "lng": -122.258198,
         "moving": false,
         "movingStartTime": null,
         "name": "1823U",
         "serial": "BK2007237851",
         "speed": 0,
         "state": "WA",
         "stopped": true,
         "stoppedStartTime": "2020-02-25 17:20:31",
         "tractorId": null,
         "tractorName": null,
         "tractorPower": false,
         "tractorPowerStartTime": "",
         "typeId": 3,
         "typeName": "Trailer",
         "zip": "98188"
      },
```

```
  *                                                                     
  /Free                                                                 
       docNode = yajl_stmf_load_tree('/home/smid/D#status.txt' :ErrMsg);

       If ErrMsg = '';                                                  
         list = yajl_object_find( docNode: 'data');                     
         i=0;                                                           
         DoW YAJL_ARRAY_LOOP(list: i: node);

//get trailer number from name value-works                             
           val = yajl_object_find(node: 'name');                        
            valName = yajl_get_string(val);                             
             dsply valName;                                             

             exsr FMT_TLR_KEY;                                          

             dsply @TLR1;

//Atempt to get cargoSensor data-dont work                                                                                                                                                                
          val = yajl_object_find(node: 'cargoSensor1');                  
           valCarg = yajl_is_true(val);                                  
            dsply valCarg;                                               


            exsr UPD_TLR;                                                
            exsr UPD_SAT_TLR;                                            

        EndDo;                                                           

      EndIf;                                                             

      yajl_tree_free(docNode);                                           

  *inlr = *on;
  /End-Free
```

Comment: Please include any output or errors that you are seeing when you post a question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be accessing the `cargoLoaded` array just like you accessed the `data` array:

```
  /Free                                                                 
       docNode = yajl_stmf_load_tree('/home/smid/D#status.txt' :ErrMsg);

       If ErrMsg = '';                                                  
         list = yajl_object_find( docNode: 'data');                     
         i=0;                                                           
         DoW YAJL_ARRAY_LOOP(list: i: node);

//get trailer number from name value-works                             
           val = yajl_object_find(node: 'name');                        
            valName = yajl_get_string(val);                             
             dsply valName;                                             

             exsr FMT_TLR_KEY;                                          

             dsply @TLR1;

//UPDATED CODE BLOCK HERE                                                                                                                                                          
           cargoList = yajl_object_find(node: 'cargoLoaded');                  
           DoW YAJL_ARRAY_LOOP(cargoList: j: node);
              val = yajl_object_find(node: 'cargoSensor1');                        
              valCarg = yajl_get_string(val);                             
              dsply valCarg;                                                 

              exsr UPD_TLR;                                                
              exsr UPD_SAT_TLR;
           EndDo;                                            

        EndDo;                                                           

      EndIf;                                                             

      yajl_tree_free(docNode);                                           

  *inlr = *on;
  /End-Free
```

Comment: This helped point me in the right direction. Thank you. I tried something similar before but neglected the "cargoList = yajl_object_find(node: 'cargoLoaded');"